# Wifi card not detected?

Tags: wireless

The WiFi symbol on the top right is empty and no WiFi networks appear, I try to set one up but the "device" box is greyed out. I have Ubuntu 16.04. When I enter the command `lswh -C network` I get this:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED  
description: Network controller     
product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
vendor: Broadcom Corporation
physical id: 0  
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0 
version: 01    
width: 64 bits  
clock: 33Mhz 
capabilities: cap_list  
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:94100000-94107fff

*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
 vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.  
physical id: 0
bus info pci@0000:04:00.0
 logical name: eno1 
version: 0a  
serial: dc:4a:3e:f7:23:64 
size: 10Mbit/s
capacity: 100Mbiy/s  
width: 64 bits  
clock: 33Mhz   
capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation

configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8107e-2_0.02 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s

resources: irq:129 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94004000-94004fff memory:94000000-94003fff
```

And a warning about not running this as super-user

I can access the internet if I use an Ethernet cable, or If I startup the laptop in windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the WiFi driver. Open up a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

**EDIT**

Disabling secure boot in your BIOS is also necessary for the driver to work

Comment: IT WORKED!!! Thanks, I had to disable secure boot tho

Comment: Awesome! Mark the thread as solved so others can see the possible solution :)

Comment: @LucaLaMattina if this answer works for you, please click on the tick icon to accept this answer.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. What really solved it was disabling secure boot.

Comment: @MichaelBay He didn't say that at all. He said he had to install the driver AND disable secure boot. The main solution to not having a WiFi driver is to install the WiFi driver.

Comment: @AugustinWinther That would be correct except for the fact that the proper driver was probably already there but not being loaded because secure boot is enabled and the driver is unsigned. The user could have installed it as many times they want and it **still would  show up as *unclaimed*** as long as secure boot is enabled. Now, instead of arguing about what you DON'T know, please improve your questions by [edit]ing it.

Comment: @MichaelBay very well. I'm sorry for being so ignorant. The answer is fixed.